# How to filter/show components of a particular schema in Item Selector?

Tags: 2011, cme

How to filter components of a particular mulitmedia schema whose webdav path is known ,can be done in Item Popup Selector. As per the below query parmaters i can filter all the components of a particular publication.
**/Extensions/ItemSelector/ItemSelectorPopup.htm?types=64&start=tcm:0-7-1&types=16**
What extra parameter i need to add which will filter/show only components of a particular schema.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do that use the "Where Used" feature of tridion and you will get all the component for that specific schema. 
Yes it will provide all the list of items which are used by that schema but further you can try to use url by appending the type component which is 16 , and might you get your solution.

Otherwise i think there is no other way to find out the dependent component except through the code using tom.net.